# Add dynamic link to InfoPath multi-selection field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, lookup-column, infopath-rules

I had to modify a form using InfoPath in order to achieve a feature that populates a multiple-selection field with data returned from a query (similar to what [this tutorial](http://sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=129) outlines).

Before making this change, the values where displayed in a lookup column when editing, like this.

```
|Option 1  |               |Selection 1|
|Option 2  |               |           |
|Option 3  |  [   Add>  ]  |           |
|Option 4  |  [ <Remove ]  |           |
|Option 5  |               |           |
|Option 6  |               |           |
```

When simply viewing (not editing) the item the selected value was a link to the original list item, like so:

[image: link-enabled selection]

and links to:

```
https://shr.pnt.dom/site/_Layouts/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={#XX##X##-XX#X-##X#-####-##X###X##X##}&ID=###
```

After the modification, I noticed that the selected values are not linked to the original items anymore. They only display on the view form as plaintext. **Is there a way create a link to the original list items on the secondary SP list that I pulled them from?** I'm able to use SharePoint Designer, InfoPath, or even jQuery on the form. Ideally, I'd like to generate links using SharePoint's functions or just syntax. I'm just stuck on where to start to actually accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that InfoPath forms can be edited in-browser to allow webparts to be added to the iframe that the form is loaded onto. This then allowed me to insert a CEWP after the form, after which I used jQuery to dynamically convert each span to a link back to the original list. Unfortunately, I found nothing on how to achieve this with OOTB SharePoint.